# Django: Could not parse the remainder

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I'm trying to pass a response from JsonResponse as a parameter of specific function in views. But, got the following error instead

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '${response.id_ajuan}' from '${response.id_ajuan}'
```

Here it is my code

**url.py**

```
url(r'^course-eksternal/review/(?P<id>\d+)/update$', course_eksternal.update_ajuan, name='update-ajuan')
```

**views.py**

```
# Function that pass the JsonResponse
def get_update_ajuan(request):
    ajuan = Pengajuan.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('ajuan_id'))
    res = {
        'id_ajuan': ajuan.id,
        ...
    }
    status_code = 200
    return JsonResponse(res, status=status_code)
```

**file.html**

```
# Get the JsonResponse
success : function(response) {
    $('.modal-body').empty().append(`
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{% url 'app:update-ajuan' id=${response.id_ajuan} %}" method="POST"> # Error occurs here
                ...
`);
```

Comment: You can not pass javascript variables to a `{% url ... %}`. Note that the `{% url ... %}` template tags are resolved at the *server* side, so the server never responds with `{% url ... %}`s in the response, after rendering these are "gone".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so, does that mean there is no way to pass javascript variable to ``{% url ... %}``?

Comment: indeed, unless you make an API view that would somehow construct views, but that probably overcomplicates things.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i think that i will make a new update page instead of using modal, so that i can pass the parameter in easy way. thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your success function is javascript that is running in the front-end. Django is not running your front-end and there is no processing of django templates going on here, so you can't use any django template tags.

What you will need to do is figure out what the url is in your view `get_update_ajuan` and then pass the whole url back.

```
from django.urls import reverse

def get_update_ajuan(request):
    ajuan = Pengajuan.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('ajuan_id'))
    res = {
        'id_ajuan': ajuan.id,
        'action_url': reverse("app:update-ajuan", kwargs={"id": ajuan.id},
        ...
    }
    status_code = 200
    return JsonResponse(res, status=status_code)
```

and then use that value:

```
success : function(response) {
    $('.modal-body').empty().append(`
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="${response.action_url}" method="POST"> # Error occurs here
                ...
`);
```